# Vaadin get local printers

Tags: printing, vaadin, local

I am trying to find the available printers of the local system with a Vaadin application.

I tried the

```
PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
```

But this gives me the printers of the server that Vaadin WAR is located.

Thanks in advance

Comment: most of the java code in a vaadin app is just what it is: server side code. unless you are having means to list the printers via javascript (call this code from the server to fetch the list from the browser/client), there is now way you can make this work on the "java" ends of vaadin.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have tried to find any examples but i din't manage to do it. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want a list of the client side printers? I think browsers do not share this information (same as a lot of other client related information) for security reasons: it could help identify a client or expose private information.

If you want to print something on the client side, you could prepare the UI and invoke this from server side:

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("window.print()");
```

This will open the print dialog on the client side. User just has to click "print" (or cancel). I think this is as far as it gets regarding "automatic printing".

Comment: Thank you very much for comments. I want to print direct in a selected by the user printer that is local installed in his computer, without ask him every time which printer he wants to use.

Comment: Well that is not possible with standard browsers. You could develop a program to install on the client (e.g. a windows service) that can talk to your  server application. Then this program could communicate the available printers to your server, and your server could instruct this program to print.